# Creating the Timer in Global.asax file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, global-asax

I would like to execute a storedprocedure for evey one hour and have to load the dataset in applicaion(dropdrown or some asp.net controle) **by creating the timer in Global.asax file**.

Am very very new for this kind of development, please any one could post the code or provide the exact flow what i have to do in coding and how to load the asp.net controls(dropdown or list controle).

Thank You in Advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scheduling tasks like that is not an appropriate use for an aspx application.

However, there are several hacks/workarounds you can try:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/129/Simple-task-Scheduling-using-Global.asax

You would be much better off creating windows service or use the built-in Windows scheduler.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET is the wrong tool for the job.

A web application is, by design, a request-response system.  It listens for requests, processes those requests, and returns responses.  Outside of that scope, it should be assumed that the application isn't running.  (Indeed, IIS might shut down the application for any number of reasons, waking it again on the new request.)

What you want for a scheduled task is probably a [Windows Service](http://myhosting.com/blog/2010/09/creating-windows-service-visual-studio-2010/).  This is designed to run in the background on the server.  Including a timer is pretty straightforward and it can run tasks in response to that timer's tick event.

Thinking about it... What would the web application *do* when the timer ticks?  How would it "load the data into some asp.net control" if it's executing a background-process and not actually responding to a web request?  Without a page being requested, there *is* no page to show to the user.

The way I imagine this would work is that the Windows Service would be reading some data, running some business logic to transform that data, and writing the transformed data to another table or set of tables in the database.  The web application would then just always refer to that other table or set of tables when it populates the controls on its pages.  Essentially, the web application would have *no knowledge* of the back-end process that transforms the data.  It just shows whatever the latest transformed data happens to be.

Comment: A windows service is gross overkill. Firstly, to develop one you need an entirely new project in VStudio, and you need permissions to implement it on a server. Client servers may not give you any permission other than to access SQL Server and minor executable access to run applications. An ASP.NET cached service is far better, as you can intigrate it into your existing project, no DLL hell, and no permission issues. This link has all the info https://www.codeproject.com/articles/12117/simulate-a-windows-service-using-asp-net-to-run-sc

Comment: @Fernando68: `"permission issues"` - Sure, if the available tooling is somehow *limited* then one would need to find alternative solutions. But just because you're arbitrarily not *allowed* to use a tool doesn't mean it would have been the wrong tool. `"an entirely new project"` - Are those several seconds of time that precious? `"DLL hell"` - I don't know how you're mis-managing your code to get *there*, but you're doing something wrong. Anyway, admittedly, in the nearly five years since this answer the tooling *has* improved. (e.g. Azure Web Jobs) Though the concept remains very similar.

Comment: Some of us 'hard-core' developers do not have the luxury of Azure or even beyond .Net 2! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the overkill of a service (as Fandango68 puts it in a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11452146/7733418 ) I recommend enabling periodic code in global.asax. This gets the usecase covered to track activity in the file system for a limited period of time, and  would do the job easily and effectively.

Comment: Stephen, please review my edit. The purpose is to change this from a "I agree" comment impression to a contribution of a solution - at least the very generic outline of one. Feel free to improve your post with details. And sorry if I somehow broke the core of your answer. In that case please accept my apology and fix it, so that this gets closer to [answer].